# How to check whether the Windows is using Bluetooth Classic SPP or BLE Serial profile?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I managed to create COM port communication using Bluetooth between Windows PC. How to check whether the Bluetooth standard used is Bluetooth Classic or BLE by my PC. Both PCs possess BLE drivers.

EDIT(Added the registry structure)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tM9n.png)

Answer (score 0):

If port appears under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHENUM{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&0001001d_PID&1200 then it is classic SPP service.

Comment: COM port appears in the following:

BTHENUM{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010006_PID&0001

Does that mean I am using BLE?
Can you please share any useful links or documents to support this?

I have added my registry structure as edit to the question. Please check as there is a difference in the value you shared and what I have.

Comment: Open the registry key I posted above. There are few sub keys. One of the contains parameter (value) with the COM name. There is no documentation for such things. Your device (based on what I see) is classic.

Comment: COM name as parameter is found in 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\BTHENUM\{00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb}_VID&00010006_PID&0001\7&11cad6dc&0&A86BAD5323C2_C00000000\Device Parameters

Could you please confirm which device am I using. Thanks for the help

Comment: A86BAD5323C2 - device's MAC

Comment: Sorry I meant, "Whether I am using Bluetooth or BLE"

Comment: BTHENUM - Classic; BTHLE - Low Energy.

Comment: And by the way, I forgot to say very important thing: you can not create vCOM for BLE connection cause it has absolutely different API. You can install drivers when pairing with BLE device for only few predefined services. And non of them provides vCOM support. Also there is no SPP profile defined for GATT. All BLE devices that provide SPP support (such as nRF42 or similar) implements it through customr GATT service and characteristic with custom vendor defined protocol. So in case your device (and COM port) is listed in the registry key I reffered above - it is 100% classic connection.

Comment: Thanks for the support.